# Early return from a for loop in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Now I have some Scala code similar to the following:

```
def foo(x: Int, fn: (Int, Int) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  for {
    i <- 0 until x
    j <- i + 1 until x
    if fn(i, j)
  } return true
  false
}
```

But I get the feeling that `return true` is not so functional (or maybe it is?). Is there a way to rewrite this piece of code in a more elegant way?

In general, what is the more functional (if any) way to write the return-early-from-a-loop kind of code?

Comment: You can have a look at tail recursion

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods can help, such as `find`, `exists`, etc. For your case, try this:

```
def foo2(x: Int, fn: (Int, Int) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  (0 until x).exists(i => 
     (i+1 until x).exists(j=>fn(i, j)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this lazy / short-circuted?

Comment: @ZizhengTai: Why do you think it needs to be lazy / short-circuited? `exists` will return as soon as the first element in a sequence satisfies the condition.

Comment: Good thing here is that you can compress it into a single line `(0 until x).exists(i => (i + 1 until x).exists(j => fn(i, j)))`

Answer (score 2):

Since all you are checking for is existence, you can just compose 2 uses of `exists`:

```
(0 until x).exists(i => (i + 1 until x).exists(fn(i, _)))
```

More generally, if you are concerned with more than just determining if a certain element exists, you can convert your comprehension to a series of  `Streams`, `Iterators`, or `views`, you can use `exists` and it will evaluate lazily, avoiding unnecessary executions of the loop:

```
def foo(x: Int, fn: (Int, Int) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  (for {
    i <- (0 until x).iterator
    j <- (i + 1 until x).iterator
  } yield(i, j)).exists(fn.tupled)
}
```

You can also use `map` and `flatMap` instead of a `for`, and `toStream` or `view` instead of `iterator`:

```
(0 until x).view.flatMap(i => (i + 1 until x).toStream.map(j => i -> j)).exists(fn.tupled)
```

You can also use `view` on any collection to get a collection where all the transformers are performed lazily.  This is possibly the most idiomatic way to short-circuit a collection traversal.  From [the docs on `views`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html):

> Scala collections are by default strict in all their transformers, except for `Stream`, which implements all its transformer methods lazily. However, there is a systematic way to turn every collection into a lazy one and vice versa, which is based on collection *views*. A view is a special kind of collection that represents some base collection, but implements all transformers lazily.

As far as overhead is concerned, it really depends on the specifics!  Different collections have different implementations of `view`, `toStream`, and `iterator` that may vary in amount of overhead.  If `fn` is very expensive to compute, this overhead is probably worth it, and keeping a consistent, idiomatic, functional style to your code makes it more maintainable, debuggable, and readable.  If you are in a situation that calls for extreme optimization, you may want to fall back to the lower-level constructs like `return` (which isn't without it's own overhead!).

Comment: Would it be overkill to use streams just for integer loops? I'm a little bit worried this would lead to too much overhead...

Comment: @ZizhengTai I've added a note addressing overhead and some other details.